# Usage of "From" and "Of"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Let me know what you guys think should be the correct sentence here..

> Ice cream is made **from** dairy products, such as milk and cream.

or

> Ice cream is made **of** dairy products, such as milk and cream.

---

from what I understand,

- "FROM" is used when we don't see the original products in the final products or the physical and chemical transformation is irreversible.
- "OF" is used when we use the something as it is in the final product

Comment: Both prepositions would work, but I think _from_ sounds a little better.

Comment: Don't forget "made out of".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something is made **from** {...}, {...} are presented as the elements or ingredients that went into X when it was produced.

When something is made **of** X, X is presented as the material of which it is constituted.

> The chair is made of wood.
>
> Granola is made from oats, raisins, and nuts.

For some speakers this distinction exists. For others, it doesn't.

> The epoxy is made from newly developed polymers.